# How to fix strange face-select behaviour?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

[image]

Whenever I click onto a face in edit mode, about 5 or more faces in random places all over the object gets activated. 
Even after I have installed the next version of linux min, linux mint 17.2, the problem still remains.

I am using Blender 2.69

I have tried the latest stable version of blender on 
linux mint 17.1, linux mint 17.2, ubuntu mate,
the problem never vanished.

Comment: Can you save your file as it is and upload it? Share the link here.

Comment: http://www.xup.in/dl,11838538/crazyselect.blend/

Comment: Try loading factory defaults and try again. Your mouse might be jittery for one.

Comment: loading factory defaults brings no difference, It is the same no matter if I use the Mouse pad or one of two mice.

Comment: I thought you might have had some weird settings but it works fine on my end. Try a more updated build. 2.75. If it persists you might have to file a bug report.

Comment: I am using linux mint 17.1 , when I remove and install Blender again with "sudo apt-get install blender" it allways gives me the same Blender version 2.69, do you know what to type in the command line in order to specify the version ?

Comment: This should work. http://askubuntu.com/a/585266

Comment: I installed a newer version of linux mint, the problem still remains.

Comment: Did you install a new version of Blender though?

Comment: Try grabbing it from builder.blender.org then. Problem with using older version is that blender is constantly under development.

Comment: yes, I tried both blender versions on both linux versions. How do you grab blender from builder.blender.org ? (I only now the apt-get install method)

Comment: Ok, I ve downloaded the .tar.bz2 file under builder.blender.org, decompressed it with tar xfj and hit the executable file, blender opened and the problem still remained.